# Copy pivot tables from Excel into Outlook email as an image

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy pivot tables from two Excel sheets in one workbook into an Outlook email as a picture. (Specifically a picture, rather than converting it to a HTML table.)

I tried to set it so that it runs every hour, as long as the workbook is open.

```vb
Sub RefreshAndEmailPivotTables()
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim pt1 As PivotTable
    Dim pt2 As PivotTable
    Dim time As String

    ' Get the current time and format it as a string
    time = Format(Now, "hh:mm")

    ' Set the worksheet and pivot table objects
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("New Claims AHT")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Existing Claims AHT")
    Set pt1 = ws1.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set pt2 = ws2.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    ' Refresh all data connections
   ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    ' Create a new email in Outlook
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    ' Set the email properties and paste the pivot table images
    With objEmail
        .To = "@Leaders"
        .CC = "@Colleagues"
        .Subject = "Update - " & time
        .Body = "Here are the pivot tables:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Body = .Body & "New Claims:" & vbNewLine
               
         'COPY PIVOTTABLE1 FROM "New Claims AHT" Sheet and paste into email body - Advice here please? :)
        
        .Body = .Body & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Existing Claims:" & vbNewLine
        
        'COPY PIVOTTABLE1 FROM "Existing Claims AHT" Sheet - Advice here please? :)

        .Display
    End With

    ' Schedule the macro to run again in one hour
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("01:00:00"), "RefreshAndEmailPivotTables"

    ' Clean up
    Set objEmail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set pt1 = Nothing
    Set pt2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried `.Copy` and `.Paste`.

I am given the error

> object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Formst the workbook / table(s) to fill the screen then printscreen...

Comment: If `pt` is set to your Pivot Table object, you can use the `.CopyPicture` method. eg: `Union(pt.DataLabelRange, pt.DataBodyRange).CopyPicture`.  Then paste into your email.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When I do this I get a Run Time Error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method) on the .Paste Line, I've just got a line with .Paste - do I need to amend this as well?

Comment: Probably depends on what the dot `.`  refers to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what to add before this - relatively new to vba! This is what I've got so far - do you know what I need to reference before .Paste?

Comment: ' Set the email properties and paste the pivot table images
    With objEmail
        .To = "Leaders"
        .CC = "Colleagues"
        .Subject = "AHT Update - " & time
        .Body = "Here are the pivot tables:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Body = .Body & "New Claims:" & vbNewLine
               
         'COPY PIVOTTABLE1 FROM "New Claims AHT" Sheet
         Union(pt1.DataLabelRange, pt1.DataBodyRange).CopyPicture
         .Paste
        
        .Body = .Body & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Existing Claims:" & vbNewLine
        
      etc.

Comment: As you can see, code in a comment is unreadable. However, a little research suggests that you will need to "paste" the image as an html **image**. There are references in this forum for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, you need to use an html body, and use this function I found to help export ranges as images.
I only included the portions required to generate the email.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RefreshAndEmailPivotTables()
    
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Dim PivotImage As String
    Dim ImageName As String
    
    ' Create a new email in Outlook
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    PivotImage = "C:\Users\cameron\Documents\Workspaces\"
    ImageName = "MyImage"
    
    ' Save Pivot, you might need to some other stuff to figure out how to _
        identify used range for the pivot. You can alos do this twice with _
        different imagenames do get both pivots.
    SaveAsImage Sheet4.Range("C4:G16"), PivotImage & ImageName
    
    With objEmail
        .To = "@Leaders"
        .CC = "@Colleagues"
        .Subject = "Update - " & Time
        
        .Attachments.Add PivotImage & ImageName & ".png", 1, 0
        
        .HTMLBody = "<html><body>" & _
                    "Here are the pivot tables: <br> <br> " & _
                    "<img src=" & ImageName & ".png> <br> <br> " & _
                    "This is the line below <br> " & _
                    "And Another Line <br> " & _
                    "Here's Another <br> " & _
                    "You could add in your second pivot image here (same as first) <br> " & _
                    "</body></html>"
        
        '.Body = "Here are the pivot tables:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        '.Body = .Body & "New Claims:" & vbNewLine
        'COPY PIVOTTABLE1 FROM "New Claims AHT" Sheet and paste into email body - Advice here please? :)
        '.Body = .Body & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Existing Claims:" & vbNewLine
        'COPY PIVOTTABLE1 FROM "Existing Claims AHT" Sheet - Advice here please? :)

        .Display
    End With
End Sub
Function SaveAsImage(RG As Range, Loc As String)
    
    'Found this in the form of a subruitine here:
    ' "https://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-save-table-as-jpeg/"
    ' by "azurous"
    ' Made a couple small changes but basically identical.
    ' Great little solution!
    
    Dim i  As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim objPic As Shape
    Dim objChart As Chart

    Call RG.CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)

    intCount = Sheet2.Shapes.Count
    For i = 1 To intCount
        Sheet2.Shapes.Item(1).Delete
    Next i

    Sheet2.Shapes.AddChart
    Sheet2.Activate
    Sheet2.Shapes.Item(1).Select
    Set objChart = ActiveChart

    objChart.Paste
    objChart.Export (Loc & ".png")
    
End Function
```

[image]

Remember `<br>` is line-break in HTML